# Converting a curl to PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, curl, header, session-cookies

I am trying to convert these two `curl` commands. I am just unsure on outputing the verbose. And if my cookie needs I2KBRCK=1. And how to do a header dump.

```batch
%CURL_FOLDER%\curl --verbose --insecure --cookie-jar %OUTPUT_FOLDER%\cookiejar.txt --cookie I2KBRCK=1 --data user@web.org --data password=pass --dump-header %OUTPUT_FOLDER%\headers_received_1.txt --output %OUTPUT_FOLDER%\curl_output_1.html --location https://website.com/action/doLogin  > %OUTPUT_FOLDER%\curl_verbose_output.txt 2>&1
%CURL_FOLDER%\curl --verbose --insecure --cookie %OUTPUT_FOLDER%\cookiejar.txt --form file1=@%TSV_UPLOAD_FILE% --form format="XYZ User License Upload" --form email=email.org --dump-header %OUTPUT_FOLDER%\headers_received_2.txt --output %OUTPUT_FOLDER%\curl_output_2.html https://website.com/something >> %OUTPUT_FOLDER%\curl_verbose_output.txt 2>&1
```

I converted the curl commands into this powershell.

```bsh
$outFilePath = 'C:\Users\blah\Desktop\curl_output_1.html'
$outFilePathVerbose = 'C:\Users\blah\Desktop\curl_verbose_output.txt'

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("user@web.org", $secpasswd)

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://website.com/doLogin" -Credential $mycreds -Verbose -SessionVariable myWebSession -Method Post -OutFile $outFilePath 
Invoke-WebRequest -InFile $someFile -Uri "https://website.com/something" -Credential $mycreds -Verbose -WebSession $myWebSession -Method Post -OutFile $outFilePath
```

I tried to convert the second curl command into powershell another way and got a 404 error instead of a 500 error...

```
$body = @"
format = "XYZUser License Upload"
file1 = $FullPathTSVToSend
"@
$gist =  Invoke-WebRequest -Body $body   -Uri "https://website.com/action/directSubscriptionUpload"  -Credential $mycreds -Verbose -WebSession $myWebSession -OutFile $outFilePath -Method Post   -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

I edited with powershell with the new code that you suggested...

```
$content = Get-Content  $FullPathTSVToSend
$body = @{ 'format' = "XYZUser License Upload"; 'file1' = $( $content); 'email' ="user@web.org"  }
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://website.com/doLogin" -Credential $mycreds -Verbose -SessionVariable myWebSession -Method Post -OutFile $outFilePath 
Invoke-WebRequest -Body $body -Uri "https://website.com/something" -Credential $mycreds -Verbose  -OutFile $outFilePath2 -Method Post -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -WebSession $myWebSession
```

However, I am still getting the 404 error for the second Invoke-WebRequest. I think maybe there is something else I need to pass from the first Invoke-WebRequest command. But the myWebSession should have that cookie I2KBRCK=1 from the first curl command.

Comment: So what's your goal here exactly?

Comment: I am having trouble converting this part of the curl command: file1=@%TSV_UPLOAD_FILE% --form format="XYZ User License Upload"  into powershell Invoke-WebRequest

Comment: Windows and PowerShell versions?

Comment: powershell 5.1 and windows 10

Comment: What is in your `-InFile`?

Comment: Also, in your first `Invoke*` you're POSTing, but there's no `-Body`

Comment: I am trying to convert the curl command --form file1=@%TSV_UPLOAD_FILE% --form format="XYZ User License Upload" into a powershell invoke.... I thought of using the -InFile. Im not sure what to have in the body...

Comment: I have the first curl converted correctly. It's the second one that is giving me a 500 Internal Server error...

Comment: Are you passing the correct `Content-Type` header? Curl will use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default for POST I think. You also don't pass the login credentials in the second curl command, so you might not need `-Credential` in th second PS command

Comment: I have tried it with -Credential and passing the email by from... For Content Type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded thats 500 error  and of multipart/form-data thats 404 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the form parameters into a hash and make sure you have the *content* of the file, not the file name, in the request.

Try:

```
$body = @{ format = "XYZUser License Upload"; file1 = $(gc $FullPathTSVToSend) }
Invoke-WebRequest -Body $body -Uri "https://website.com/action/directSubscriptionUpload" -Credential $mycreds -Verbose -WebSession $myWebSession -OutFile $outFilePath -Method Post -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: I am still getting a 404 error message. I edited my question with the new code I am using...